# Image drop shadow in Swift

Tags: swift

I need help to achieve this image shadow in Swift.

[image]

I did it in HTML/CSS like this:

```
<div style="background-image:url(xxx); filter: blur(30px)"></div>
<img src="xxx">
```

Here is what I did so far:
I just dragged and dropped UIVisualEffectView from Xcode storyboard and I put it behind the UIImage (the UIVisualEffectView has the same size as the UIImageView, and is centered in the middle). The only setting of the UIVisualEffectView is "Blur Style: Light"

[image]

But the border is not fading out.

Thank you..

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Okay.. I updated the question. Thx.

Comment: Welcome to iOS programming! I believe you're headed down a wrong path. A quick search online yielded a link I've checked out before. Just remember, a `UIImageView` inherits from `UIView`. http://nscookbook.com/2013/01/ios-programming-recipe-10-adding-a-shadow-to-uiview/

Comment: I just found a solution! Here it is. ;)

Comment: Are you able to share your solution?